# Laravel 4 CMS composer module?

Tags: php, content-management-system, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I currently have an application developed on Laravel-4 we are needing to implement CMS functionality e.g. pages, posts, menu... on top of the actual application we have developed.

I do not feel like re-creating the wheel.

**Are there any recommended CMS composer modules available for Laravel-4? that can simple be integrated into an existing application with an existing admin / user / roles setup?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this date it is still in development, but the good folks at WardrobeCMS are working on exactly that:

https://twitter.com/WardrobeCMS/status/364825833715671040

You can find the repo here:
https://github.com/wardrobecms/core

Answer (score 1):

Wardrobe is great if you just need posts. At this point there isn't anything more than that though.

I haven't seen anything beyond wardrobe that is being developed as a composer package that is any better.

This has some possibilities but it requires a bit more work than just a composer install.
https://github.com/TheMonkeys/laravel-silverstripe